# FirebaseUI, Specifying a certain activity to open in a certain case (After Signing-Up)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am using FirebaseUI for Auth to handle authentication, What I want to do is to specify a certain activity to open if the user is signed-up (logged-in for the first time), Is there's a possible way to achieve this?

**EDIT:** Here's the FirebaseUi authentication used:

```
List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
                                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER).build(),
                                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER).build());

                            startActivityForResult(
                                    AuthUI.getInstance()
                                            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                            .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                                            .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                                            .setTheme(R.style.LoginTheme)
                                            .setLogo(R.drawable.ic_melomania_blue_light)
                                            .build(),
                                    RC_SIGN_IN);
```

The `onActivityResult` :

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Sign-in succeeded, set up the UI
                Toast.makeText(this, "Signed in!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // Sign in was canceled by the user, finish the activity
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sign in canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }}
```

Comment: "How to" questions are difficult to answer, and tend to generate follow-up discussions. To improve your chances of getting a helpful answer, [edit] your question to provide greater focus on the specific problem you're facing. See [ask].

Comment: do you want the user to go to that activity on every login?

Comment: @PeterHaddad only after signing-up.

Comment: @RanX okay check the answer please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend checking out the [docs](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/auth#handling-the-sign-in-response). Here's an example of how you would handle the response from your activity:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // RC_SIGN_IN is the request code you passed into startActivityForResult(...) when starting the sign in flow.
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);

        // Successfully signed in
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            startActivity(SignedInActivity.createIntent(this, response)); // <--- This is what you are looking for!
            finish();
        } else {
            // Sign in failed
            if (response == null) {
                // User pressed back button
                showSnackbar(R.string.sign_in_cancelled);
                return;
            }

            if (response.getError().getErrorCode() == ErrorCodes.NO_NETWORK) {
                showSnackbar(R.string.no_internet_connection);
                return;
            }

            showSnackbar(R.string.unknown_error);
            Log.e(TAG, "Sign-in error: ", response.getError());
        }
    }
}
```

And to specifically check if this is a first time user, take a look at [this example](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md#user-metadata):

```
FirebaseUserMetadata metadata = auth.getCurrentUser().getMetadata();
if (metadata.getCreationTimestamp() == metadata.getLastSignInTimestamp()) {
    // The user is new, show them a fancy intro screen!
} else {
    // This is an existing user, show them a welcome back screen.
}
```

Comment: But as far as I understand, this would work whenever I sign in and What I want to do instead is the make that certain activity appears only after registering for the first time.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhh, I see. Check out my updated answer then.

Answer (score 1):

To go to a specific activity after the user sign up in Firebase, you can do this:

```
 auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(StudentSignUpActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            Toasty.info(getApplicationContext(), "creation of account was: " + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,ActivityYouWantToGoTo.class));
                                finish();
```

After the user enters the email and the password, then you can use the above method to authenticate the user and if it was successful it will redirect the user to the activity that you want, using this:

```
 startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,ActivityYouWantToGoTo.class));
```

the above activity names are just samples, you should change them depending on your activity name.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but I'm using FirebaseUi :
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md#identity-provider-configuration
I have edited the question details, If you can, could you check them again? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have already done that, but unfortunately, it doesn't specify how to achieve this specific action after signing up only.

Comment: If I added it in onActivityResult it still won't specify the action for signing up only which is the problem, I have added my onActivityResult in the question.

Comment: @RanX see this demo: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md#demo. Also below it says `If a user is not currently signed in, as can be determined by checking auth.getCurrentUser() != null,hen the sign-in process can be started by creating a sign-in intent using AuthUI.SignInIntentBuilder. A builder instance can be retrieved by calling createSignInIntentBuilder() on the retrieved AuthUI instance.`